# What is wrong with my 'proof' that there is only ever one Borel subgroup of an algebraic group

Tags: lie-groups, algebraic-groups

Let $G$ be an algebraic group. Let $\mathfrak{B}$ be the collection of Borel subgroups of $G$. Let $S$ be a connected, solvable, normal subgroup of $G$. Denote the identity component of the subgroup $H\subset G$ by $H^\circ$.

Which incorrect statement is generating my contradiction?

1. Since the Borel subgroups are maximal with respect to being connected and solvable, $S\subseteq B$ for some $B\in\mathfrak{B}$.
2. The Borel conjugacy theorem tells us $gSg^{-1}\subseteq gBg^{-1}=B'$, for some $B'\in\mathfrak{B}$.
3. Since $S$ is normal, $gSg^{-1}=S\subseteq B'$.
4. We can conclude that $S$ is in every Borel subgroup. $S\subseteq \bigcap_{B\in \mathfrak{B}}B$.
5. The identity component of a group is the **unique** irreducible component containing the identity.
6. $S$ contains the identity and since it is connected, it is
   irreducible.
7. From 5. and 6. both $B^\circ$ and $S$ are irreducible and contain the identity. But the uniqueness tells us that $S=B^\circ$. Since $B$ is connected, $B=B^\circ$, and hence $S=B$.
8. This holds for every Borel. So $S$ is equal to every Borel, and hence there is only ever one Borel subgroup. **Contradiction.**

Of course I don't believe the conclusion, but I was trying to show that $S\subseteq \left(\bigcap_{B\in\mathfrak{B}} B\right)^\circ$, and obviously one of my deductions is false.

Comment: So $G$ is a topological group, not a mere algebraic one.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Algebraic group, meaning an algebraic variety with group structure, where the multiplication and inverse are morphisms of varieties. (I don't study Lie groups, but I think perhaps all of these steps hold there for Lie groups too)

(Not explaining it to you because I think you don't know, just ensuring the terminology is the same)

Comment: Where does 1. come from? Why cannot we take $B = G$?

Comment: @HennoBrandsma $G$ may not be connected or solvable.

Comment: [these notes](http://www.hcm.uni-bonn.de/fileadmin/perrin/ag-chap7.pdf) are probably relevant?

Comment: I don't understand step 7. Considering Lie groups instead for a moment, if $G$ is simple, then $S=1$ is the only possible choice for $S$ and obviously step 7 is wrong.

Comment: You don't say that $B$ has to be, Why does being maximal imply that there is one containing it? ANd why not take $B = \overline{S}$, e.g.? That is connected and normal when $S$ is.

Comment: What is the logic in step 7. I don't see any justification for the conclusion $S=B^\circ$?

Comment: I don't understand step 7, which seems to me to be pretty clearly where the mistake is. What does $(-)^{\circ}$ mean? In general, if you want to find out what goes wrong in an argument like this you should run through it with a particular example, say $G = GL_2$ and $S$ the center.

Comment: Are you thinking that the connectivity components of $S$ and $B$ are somehow equal? BTW, +1 for showing the reasoning! Also, Qiaochu Yuan's suggestion to test the argument with a dry run (implicit in Ted's comment also) is excellent.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Each $B\in \mathcal{B}$ is a Borel subgroup, so maximal with respected to connectedness and solvability, so if $S$ is solvable and connected, it must belong to some Borel, I just let that specific one be $B$.

Comment: I am considering your responses still. I will run through $\text{GL}_2$ now

Comment: Re: the edit of step 7. There are several connected, irreducible, solvable subgroups containing the identity. Their dimensions may vary.

Comment: The components of a subgroup usually are not components of the big group. If this were so, it would imply that connected groups cannot have any proper connected subgroups at all.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Thank you, very true!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The error is in step seven:

> 7. From 5. and 6. both $B^\circ$ and $S$ are irreducible and contain the identity. But the uniqueness tells us that $S=B^\circ$. Since $B$ is connected, $B=B^\circ$, and hence $S=B$.

As noted in the comments; the components of a subgroup are not necessarily components of the big group. So $S=S^\circ$ is not necessarily a component of $B$, and hence we cannot use the uniqueness of the identity component to deduce that $S=B^\circ$.